# I am getting this error when trying to import list of youtube urls

Tags: python, dataframe

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/zeesu/PycharmProjects/ReadCSVFile/Youtube/scrol_link2.py", line 50, in <module>
    df1 = pd.read_csv("C:/Stock_in_CFD/Spicy_Treats/Output2.txt",header=None)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 678, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 440, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 787, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1014, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1708, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 542, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

I am getting this when I trying to import this data

```
https:\www.youtube.com/watch?v=NcANm_CjVYA
https:\www.youtube.com/watch?v=NcANm_CjVYA
https:\www.youtube.com/watch?v=HSPyLfwfHs8
https:\www.youtube.com/watch?v=HSPyLfwfHs8
https:\www.youtube.com/watch?v=zoi6ioQ7-pY



downloaded = open("C:/Stock_in_CFD/Spicy_Treats/title.txt", 'a+', encoding='utf-8')
df1 = pd.read_csv("C:/Stock_in_CFD/Spicy_Treats/Output2.txt",header=None)
```

This is code I am using.
 I tried various option like deifing delimter etc but didn't help. WHat I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Hard to tell without the possibility of having a look at the file you are trying to read. However, being the error of type 'EmptyDataError', it looks like it could be an empty data file. The documentation also says that this error can also occur if a header is encountered.